# Schur product theorem

Tags: matrices, semidefinite-programming, hadamard-product

The theorem states that the Hadamard product of two positive definite matrices $ A \circ B$  is also positive definite. Can I make any statement about a the Hadamard product of a  positive definite matrix $A$ and a non-positive definite matrix $C$? Specifically, does it follow that the result is not positive definite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\3&1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Here $A$ and $A\circ B$ are positive definite, $B$ is not. Any positive definite diagonal matrix will do in place of $A$, and it even still works if the off-diagonal entries of $A$ are nonzero but small.

Comment: Thank you for the counter example! Is there any way to quantify  "nonzero but small" (this is exactly the scenario which I'm considering, i.e., A is symmetric) ?

Comment: In the case at hand, less than $1/3$. Just make sure the Schur product is "diagonally dominant".